# Execution failed for task :app:processDebugManifest Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I'm getting a compile error after adding **CardView** and **RecyclerView** dependencies, I've checked every post but no one seems to solve this case.

Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

My Build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soft.kukito.cardviewprueba"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Thank everyone for answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the same android support library version. You need to use support library `26.0.0-alpha1` version. So change the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

You also need to change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to version **26**.

Comment: If i change that, would it works  for example in Loollipop after compile?

Comment: it will support the minimum sdk that you set in `minSdkVersion`. In your case, you use `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 25` which telling the Android Studio to build the project to support Android Lollipop (5.0) to Android 7.1