# Execution failed for task':app:processDebugManigest'

Tags: android, firebase

I got this error code in my code:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

This is how my gradle(project-level) looks like:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.mertalptasdelen.chatapp"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 26
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
```

These are my project dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.4.0'
```

Also, I read this answer link [Execution failed for task :app:processDebugManifest Android Studio 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134998/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugmanifest-android-studio-2-3-3) it's similar to my error(maybe same) but I'm unable to solve it.

Comment: have you added maven Google to your project level gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587751/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugmanifest)

Comment: @NovoLucas it's already added

Comment: @WiktorEriksson i tried what they say here but it doesnt work

Comment: Error description in event log like that: error getting error html: unexpected add suggestion format add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related with firebase-ui library. From its [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android):

> Upgrading dependencies
>
> If you would like to use a newer version of one of FirebaseUI's
>   transitive dependencies, such as Firebase, Play services, or the
>   Android support libraries, you need to add explicit compile
>   declarations in your build.gradle for all of FirebaseUI's dependencies
>   at the version you want to use.

Because you use all of the `firebase-ui`, you need to add the specific support library version to your **build.gradle**. Something like this:

```
//auth:
compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"

//Database:
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0"

//Storage:
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0"
```

And because you use `firebase-ui:2.4.0`, you need to use Firebase/Google Play version `11.4.0`. So, change your firebase dependency to 11.4.0:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
```

Comment: It's working !! Thanks a lot but now when emulator starts app opened but it gave me this window "App won't run unless you update the Google Play service" :(